# Will I get an error message if I ordered a domain name which turns to not be available?

Tags: google-domains

When [reading the terms of service](https://domains.google.com/tos), I saw :

> Google does not guarantee that Registrant will be able to register or renew a desired domain name, even if Google’s systems indicate that the domain name is available or **Registrant is able to complete an order** with respect to such domain name.

and

> Registrar shall give no guarantee for a successful allocation of ordered domains and becomes free from the duty to perform the service in case of impossibility of the order.

Will I get an error messages in the webapp if I order a domain which isn't available, or will it silently fail *(by silently fail I mean the website still claims I own the domain because the order was successful)* ?
I can't test it since no bank allow to open accounts in foreign currencies for individuals in my country *(the foreign currency being $)*

If it silently fails, then it would confirm a server security vulnerability *(I would be able to take ownership of the google.com domain in Webmaster Tools)*.

Answer (score 1):

Generally you will be informed at the time of order if you are unable to register the domain name as it has already been taken. If for some other reason you are unable to register the domain after you have already submitted the request and paid for it then it depends on the way that the registrar operates but generally you will receive an email and/or a message on the website saying that the registration failed and possibly even the reason why it failed. This most commonly occurs when a regulatory issue for a registration is not met such as registering a .org domain name when your registration does not meet the requirements for having a .org domain name.